# Spring upgrade causes JPA Date field to serialise in the wrong format

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, jackson

I have an entity with a Date field like so:

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private Date timestamp;
}
```

This "timestamp" field has always been serialised as milliseconds-from-epoch (eg. 1593779821000). Following a Spring Boot upgrade, it now returns a date string for some reason (eg. "2020-12-09T07:52:06.000+00:00"). I have searched high and low for an explaination of this and how to get back the correct behaviour but there is nothing. Does anyone know what annotation is needed to fix this or why on Earth they felt the need to change it in the first place??

Comment: According to https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat millisecond timestamp is the default format. Clearly it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem is that all the online information is simply wrong.

I found a dozen websites (from 2017) claiming that `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps` defaults to `true` but this is clearly not the case anymore.

Cannot find any official documentation for this property. No mention of this change in any change logs or release notes. Wish I could say I was surprised but Spring introduces application breaking changes all the time without telling anyone.